# Permission required for the server less deploy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

When creating an IAM user/group to run the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=y serverless deploy -v` on aws lambda,
what roles/permissions should be granted to that user/group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Serverless Framework documentation,

> To let the Serverless Framework access your AWS account, we're going to create an **IAM User with Admin access**, which can configure the services in your AWS account.
>
> Note: In a production environment, we recommend reducing the permissions to the IAM User which the Framework uses. Unfortunately, the Framework's functionality is growing so fast, we can't yet offer you a finite set of permissions it needs (we're working on this).

In the production environment, IAMFullAccess, AWSLambdaFullAccess and CloudFormationFullAccess should be enough.

Comment: The list of profiles needed is `serverless.yml` dependent (e.g. is a function triggered by an APIGateway event? then the IAM user will need APIGateway permission, etc.)

Comment: `FullAccess` anything *in a production environment* is a **terrible** idea. For development, with appropriate  precautions (sandboxing/etc.), it *can* do more good than harm.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 update:** Serverless.com now has an [at least partial] solution to determine a set of privileges that a diven deploy will require: https://www.serverless.com/blog/abcs-of-iam-permissions#managing-permissions-for-the-serverless-framework-user

tl;dr:

- it involves npm's `Yeoman` package and `generator-serverless-policy`
- `This will create a JSON file in your working directory with permissions scoped to your service. It's not perfect, but it will get you closer.`